# select two record containing dates in it with two input dates

Tags: select

Simply I have Two Input box

1. Start_date
2. End_date

This is my database table

```
| id | category | start_date | end_date   |
| 1  | gold     | 2016-05-24 | 2016-05-31 |
| 2  | silver   | 2016-05-16 | 2016-05-23 |
```

Now When I insert date like below:

```
start_date = 2016-05-25
end_date = 2016-05-27
```

I want to find out category between imputed date in input box.

I use this select query:

```
SELECT category 
FROM tablename
WHERE '$start_date','$end_date' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

But I don't get any result. I know that if you use single date after where I get result but I want to search with two dates

Comment: It's not clear why you want both rows returned. Are you looking for rows that their range is "overlapping" with the range in the parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer:

If you want both date columns to be between the input dates:

```
SELECT category 
FROM tablename 
WHERE 'start_date' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
  AND 'end_date' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date ;
```

Or if you want any of the date columns to be between the input dates:

```
SELECT category 
FROM tablename 
WHERE 'start_date' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
   OR 'end_date' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date ;
```

Or if you want any of the ranges that are "overlapping with the range of the input dates
(seems the most likely, based on the wanted result):

```
SELECT category 
FROM tablename 
WHERE 'start_date' <= end_date
  AND start_date <= 'end_date' ;
```

Comment: this query show only one result if i search as 
Start_date = 2016-05-16
end_date= 2016-05-31 then actually i have to get both category. but using this query i did't get a result. i get empty return.  @Frederico Almeida

Comment: it depends on your data. If your field is datetime then sql server will convert the input date to datetime. For example: Input end date = 2016-05-31 then SQL will convert to datetime 2016-05-31 00:00:00. If your date in the table is 2016-05-31 01:00:00 then SQL will not get this result. Try converting your input date to datetime 2016-05-31 23:59:59.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use below query for your output.

```
SELECT category 
 FROM table_1 
   WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2016-05-16' AND '2016-05-31'
    OR end_date BETWEEN '2016-05-16' AND '2016-05-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably table row interval must be within interval defined by user input (`'$start_date'`, `'$end_date'`). So

```
SELECT category 
FROM tablename t 
WHERE t.start_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'  
    AND t.end_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date';
```